# Terminal stops printing even with a running process

Tags: c, sockets, unix, terminal, gnome-terminal

I have tried to open a child process in a new terminal but found no solution online or in any book.
I recently studied about Unix Domain Sockets and passing file descriptors and tried to achieve it using these.

The following is the pseudo-code for my program. `send_fd` and `recv_fd` are function for passing fds as defined in the Richard Stevens book.

The programs are working almost as expected. The output and input of the child process are redirected to the newly created terminal. But the child process is only able to print as long as process `temp` is still running. When `temp` terminates, child stops printing in the new terminal and the new terminal closes. How should I overcome this? Thanks in advance.

```
int forknt()
{
    system("gnome-terminal -- \"./temp\""); //run auxiliary program in a new terminal
    //sfd is fd of the unix domain socket used to connect to ./temp
    int fd0 = recv_fd(sfd); //get stdin of new terminal
    int fd1 = recv_fd(sfd); //get stdout of new terminal
    int c = fork();
    if(!c)
    {
        dup2(fd0, 0);
        dup2(fd1, 1);
    }
    close(sfd);
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int c = forknt();
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Code for auxiliary program `temp`

```
int main()
{
    send_fd(sfd, 0);
    send_fd(sfd, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminal program, which sets up the standard input and output of the sub-process it starts and connects them to itself for I/O, will also terminate when the sub-process terminates.  If instead you tell `gnome-terminal` to start a shell after the first `./temp` program terminates, then it will stay open and I think then your first program should be able to continue to read and write to the transferred file descriptors.

```
gnome-terminal -- "./temp; exec sh"
```

See [this Unix answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373188/29168).